# How to hide/show div using jQuery without altering dimensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that is holding a google chart:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

It has one CSS property: `display: none`.

On the click of a button, I would like to have the chart be displayed using jQuery hide() and show(). It's working, however, the chart's dimensions are set to something different than I have specified and refuse to change to what I have specified.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chart = $('#chart_div'); 

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        chart.show('slow'); 
    });
});
```

Let me know if theres any more code you would like to see. By the way, the chart div is not being contained in anything else so that isn't the problem.

Comment: First of all, is it possible that what you see is the overflow of the map inside your div? try giving a border to your div ( or inspect it with a debugger ) to see it's dimensions and if the div is your problem or not. If you can, make a working jsFiddle so we can see the code for this div with the map inside.

Comment: Well here's the code, but it doesn't seem to display the graph at all. It's working in my browser though.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wmnyc/

Comment: be sure to add whatever external js and css files are needed for this chart.

Comment: That's all of it. 
edit: i've simplified the JSFiddle. You can see the issue now: http://jsfiddle.net/fmqvR/

Answer (score 3):

Your div is fine. You have to set the chart dimensions by using the API options.
Look here --> [customizing the chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart)

```
// Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};
```

so in your case
---> http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/8cpgd/2/

...

```
    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        width: 600,
        height: 300
    };
```

...

By the way, next time be careful on using Google api in jsfiddle   http://www.imarichardson.com/2011/02/08/google-jsapi-jsfiddle-relationship-problems/